# How to make exceptions in SAS eg

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

In python you can make exception like this:

```
x=0
try:
       1/x
except:
       1+2
```

So if you get an error in the first statement the second one is runs

Does SAS EG have something similar?

I try to do something like this:

```
try:
%_eg_conditional_dropds(WORK.QUERY_FOR_KUNDE_REA_UDL_20_0000);

PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_KUNDE_REA_UDL_20_0000 AS 
   SELECT t1.Z_ORDINATE, 
          /* KundeNum */
            (input(t1.cpr_se,w.)) AS KundeNum
      FROM &str_PERIOKVT_PREV_YYMMN6;
QUIT;

except:
%_eg_conditional_dropds(WORK.QUERY_FOR_KUNDE_REA_UDL_20_0000);

PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_KUNDE_REA_UDL_20_0000 AS 
   SELECT t1.Z_ORDINATE, 
          /* KundeNum */
            (input(t1.cpr_se,w.)) AS KundeNum
      FROM &str_PERIOKVT_PREV_YYMMN6_v2;
QUIT;
```

I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS does not have try/except blocks, but you can work around it a number of ways. Here are two effective ways of handling it.

The most common way is by specifying the error condition you're looking for. For example, let's say we know our code will fail if `&str_PERIOKVT_PREV_YYMMN6` does not exist. We can first check for that before running the code using macro functions:

```
%if(%sysfunc(exist(&str_PERIOKVT_PREV_YYMMN6))) %then %do;
    <code>;
%end;
    %else %do;
        <code>;
    %end;
```

A more generic way is to use the `&syserr.` macro variable. This value is updated each time a procedure is run. If this value is > 6, an error has occurred:

```
/* Try running code */
data test;
    set fakedata;
run;

/* If something goes wrong, then do something else */
%if(&syserr. > 6) %then %do;
    %put ERROR: Something went wrong! Error code: &syserr.;
%end;
```

More information on `&syserr` can be found here:
https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/n1wrevo4roqsnxn1fbd9yezxvv9k.htm

Comment: Thank you! In your examples is it possible to loop them until there is no more errors? How would you do that if it is possible?

Comment: You would encapsulate the code in a macro that loops indefinitely until &syserr returns <= 6. e.g. `%do %until(&syserr. LE 6);`